Are these variables equal because they reference the same instance even though it seems like they should have different values?
previous code
from bakery import assert_equal
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    length: int
    width: int

def stretch(rect: Rectangle) -> Rectangle:
    rect.length = rect.length * 2
    return rect

box = Rectangle(5, 3)
assert_equal(stretch(box), Rectangle(10, 3))

confusing part
def stretch(rect: Rectangle) -> Rectangle:
    rect.length = rect.length * 2
    return rect

box = Rectangle(5,3)
wide_box = stretch(box)


The lesson I'm learning with (vscode.dev/edu) said that all three variables (box, rect, and wide_box) are equivalent because they point to the same instance. What does this mean? Doesn't wide_box double the value of box? And rect seems basically theoretical so what value does it even have?

stretch() modifies the Rectangle you passed to it, and returns the very same Rectangle.  wide_box is indeed double the length that box had, but box is also double the length that box had.

rect is temporary (it only exists while stretch() is running), not theoretical. During that time it has the same value as box.

In Python, the usual convention is that a function either modifies its input value and doesn't return anything, or returns a new object with the modified values. So a function like stretch(), which modifies its input in place and also returns the input, is unusual.

Mandatory link to Ned Batchelder

To get what I think you were expecting, it should be def stretch(rect: Rectangle) -> Rectangle: return Rectangle(length=rect.length * 2, width: rect.width)

stretch(box) is just doubling the length of that Rectangle object. So if:
box1 = Rectangle(5,5)
box2 = Rectangle(10,5)

then calling stretch on box1 will make it equivalent to box2. So:
box2 == stretch(box1) # because these are both length of 10 and width of 5

They're not equal because they point to the same instance; they are equal because all their properties are the same.
rect is just what these boxes are called locally within the stretch function. The box function is just saying I accept a Rectangle object as a parameter and I am going to call it rect while I am working with it.

This answer is misleading, as box and wide_box do in fact refer to the same instance in the question. The questioner wanted to write a function that would make a new instance, but failed to do so, due to misunderstanding what operations make copies in Python.

Yes sorry box and wide box refer to the same instance. I was talking about in the assert.

@user2357112 I think it's important in Python to understand that assigning something either through an assignment = or as a parameter of a function call does not make a copy.  If you want a copy you need to be explicit about it (see Zen of Python).
